# How can I use placement.info to place a specific field on a specific part in Orchard?

Tags: orchardcms

I have an Address part with a Street1 field. I would like to use some syntax in placement.info similar to this in order to specify placement:

```
<Place Fields_Common_Text_Edit-Address-Street1="Group1:0" />
```

I have multiple parts on my content type that have fields with the same name, so I can't just use Fields_Common_Text_Edit-Street1. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please set my reply as answer if it helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `[ShapeType]__[ContentType]__[PartName]__[FieldName]` pattern ([see the docs](http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Alternates)), i.e. this should work:

```
<Place Fields_Common_Text_Edit-YourType-Address-Street1="Group1:0" />
```